# Is there any solution for Ubuntu-18.04 sound problem?

Tags: audio, ubuntu-18.04

I am new with Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu on my computer and some time after, sound was gone. I tried some methods which explained in forums but i can't solve problem. Than i setup Ubuntu again. First 6 hour, there was no problem with sound but it gone again.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is just putting the computer to sleep and waking it up again, and the problem will solve. Solution is at link below.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/955065/no-sound-on-ubuntu-windows-dual-boot/1016960#1016960